# How do I get PyParsing set up on the Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyparsing

I saw on the Google App Engine documentation that http://www.antlr.org/ Antlr3 is used as the parsing third party library.

But from what I know Pyparsing seems to be the easier to use and I am only aiming to parse some simple syntax.

Is there an alternative? Can I get pyparsing working on the App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Just do it"!-)  Get pyparsing.py, e.g. from [here](http://pyparsing.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pyparsing/src/pyparsing.py?revision=181), and put it in your app engine app's directory; now you can just `import pyparsing` in your app code and use it.

For example, tweak the greeting.py from [here](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/page/view/home/81583791) to be:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas
greet = Word( alphas ) + "," + Word( alphas ) + "!" # <-- grammar defined here
hello = "Hello, World!"
print "Content-type: text/plain\n"
print hello, "->", greet.parseString( hello )
```

add to your app.yaml right under `handlers:` the two lines:

```
- url: /parshello
  script: greeting.py
```

start your app, visit `http://localhost:8083/parshello` (or whatever port you're running on;-), and you'll see in your browser the plain text output:

```
Hello, World! -> ['Hello', ',', 'World', '!']
```

Answer (score 4):

Pyparsing's runtime footprint is intentionally small for just this purpose.  It is a single source file, pyparsing.py, so just drop it in amongst your own source files and parse away!

-- Paul

Comment: are you going to move your pyparsing support over here, Paul?  Rather than the secret spot on your wiki?